# Show image before upload. Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, internet-explorer, safari

I got a script where i can upload an image. After you found your image. You click ok. The image will be showed before its uploaded.

It works in **Firefox** and **Chrome**. But it doesnt work in **Safari** and **IE**. The code i use is:

**Javascript**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PreviewImage() {
        oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("img").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };
    };

</script>
```

**Html**:

```
<input id="file" type="file" onchange="PreviewImage();"/>
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/high-resolution-fantasy-woman.jpg" id="img" class="img" width="371" height="auto" style="top:-0px; left:-0px;" />
```

Live example:
http://jewelbeast.com/posts/ 
This link works in **Chrome** and **Firefox**. But not in **IE** and **Safari**. And thats the problem i want that it works in IE and Safari.

And i know i used **Javascript**. And I also tried **jQuery** but than i had the same problem.

Dennis,

Comment: What versions of IE is important here.

Comment: The image will be showed before its uploaded. => I do not think this is technically possible

Comment: Ok maybe not in IE. But is it possible for safari?

Comment: Probably it is not possible but check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427061/show-image-before-upload-safari-and-ie

Comment: Thats a link to my post ;)

Comment: @Pleun its working for Chrome and FireFox. If Safari works to. Than i will be happy. I dont care alot about IE :P

Comment: Safari for OS X - It should work.

Comment: @DennisBetman: also in Chrome and FirFox it will not be possible because if it is shown in the webpage it means it is already uploaded to the webserver (perhaps not saved/posted in the database but the upload has already taken place for sure)

Comment: @pleun look http://jewelbeast.com/posts/ you can choose an image and it shows the image. ;)

Comment: A i understand what you mean. nvm  ;)